# JW Player 6: Adding multiple sources to a playlist

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

So I've seen the [original example](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439570-example-loading-new-playlists) of how to load playlists from a link. And I know there's an [API method](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference#playlist) `playlist[].sources[].file` to add sources. I'm just having difficulty with putting it all together. I tried to be tricky by just loading the name of the file, but it get's a bad playlist error.

```
<div>Watch the quick tutorial on <a href="javascript:loadVideo('basics','_images/title2.png')">the basics</a> or <a href="javascript:loadVideo('destruction','_images/title2.png')">destruction</a>.</div>
<div id="tutorial">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myFile = 'basics';
    var myImage = '_images/title2.png';

    jwplayer("tutorial").setup({
        width: 512,
        height: 320,
        playlist: [{
            image: "_images/title2.png",
            sources: [
                {file: "_media/"+myFile+".webm"},
                {file: "_media/"+myFile+".mp4"}
            ]
        }]
    });

    function loadVideo(myFile,myImage) {
        jwplayer().load([{
            file: myFile,
            image: myImage
        }]);
        jwplayer().play();
    };
</script>
```

How do I use the `playlist[].sources[].file` with the `load(playlist)` methods?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
function loadVideo(myFile,myImage,myFile2) {
        jwplayer().load([{
            image: myImage,
            sources: [
                {file: myFile},
                {file: myFile2}
            ]
        }]);
    jwplayer().play();
};
```

Comment: Hi Ethan, thanks for the tip, I'll try it that way. It seems like all the solutions on this site use this method. To further my understanding, what you you normally use `playlist[].sources[].file` with? Could you give me an example?

Comment: I have never used playlist[].sources[].file, I always always tried the above.

Comment: @emaxsaun Can we use above method to load more then one m3u8 streams ? if one of the m3u8 streams get 404 error does it try to play the next m3u8 stream on playlist or the player stops ?Is there away that it continues to play the next stream on the playlist ?

Comment: It should work the same regardless of the file type.